# TTP223: interaction with plastics

Tags: button, sensitivity

I amm working on a tactile button based on the TTP223.

While trying to implement it, I realized that there are unpleasant interactions with plastics.  I don't understand why.

The interactions appear when the sensor is completely in contact with the plastic surface.

Another problem: The sensor behaviour is not like a smartphone screen, because it interacts with metals and other elements.

What is the best way to create a button with similar behaviour to a smartphone screen?

P.d: I have tried to add some capacitors to configure the sensitivity and it works more or less fine (with 22 pF doesn't interact with metal touch, but interact when plastic is touching the sensor).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "unpleasant interactions", you might want to rephrase that part.

Comment: a smartphone screen is a capacitive sensor – of course it interacts with any conductor that is grounded or large enough to change the capacitance of the surface. You're probably ignoring the layers upon layers of software logic procesing the raw sensor output.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitive touch is fairly sensitive to the environment.

Smartphone usually will calibrate themselves every time you wake-up the screen and there is a lot of algorithm behind.

Given this IC is all integrated, besides playing with the Cs, there isn't much you can do.

Another option is to use MCU which has capacitive touch functionality like some PIC with mtouch.

With the MCU you have more room to do some firmware to filter out false positive, perform periodic calibration, and tailor it to your application.